# i have a json string.I need to parse it and put the values of id,company_code,..and other such values in a table

Tags: python, mysql, json

I have a json string.I need to parse it and put the values of id,company_code,..and other such values in a mysql table,but this string contains hex code i tried a for loop but it iterated char by char(coz its a string).Since am new to python am unable to get the desired output.

Here is the string:

Feb 17 03:49:03 afg-prod-web2 journal: afg-prod-web2 statistics: 192.168.28.12 - 200 - 
{\x0A    "identifier": {\x0A        "company_code": "TSC",\x0A        "product_type": "airtime-ctg",\x0A        "host_type": "android"\x0A    },\x0A    "id": {\x0A        "type": "guest",\x0A        "group": "guest",\x0A        "uuid": "8354e5f4-e18d-11e6-9a46-0242ac110002",\x0A        "device_id": "77c7600c502a3d15"\x0A    },\x0A    "stats": [\x0A        {\x0A            "timestamp": "2017-02-17T03:49:01+0000",\x0A            "software_id": "A-ACTG",\x0A            "action_id": "open_app",\x0A            "values": {\x0A                "device_id": "77c7600c502a3d15",\x0A                "language": "fr"\x0A            }\x0A        }\x0A    ]\x0A}

The code i tried:

```
with open('ctg-stats.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    splitData = data.split('"')
        for splitText in splitData:
            data2 = splitText.replace('\\x22','"')
            for column in splitText:
                print splitText[column]
```

Comment: The [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) would probably be useful...

Comment: Can you format your code and data correctly?

Comment: using json.loads(splitText) gives error No JSON object could be decoded

Answer (score 1):

With the string as-is, it is already in valid json format, you just need to parse it using `json.loads()`:

```
string = "{\x0A \x22identifier\x22: {\x0A \x22company_code\x22: \x22TSC\x22,\x0A \x22product_type\x22: \x22airtime-ctg\x22,\x0A \x22host_type\x22: \x22android\x22\x0A },\x0A \x22id\x22: {\x0A \x22type\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A \x22group\x22: \x22guest\x22,\x0A \x22uuid\x22: \x228354e5f4-e18d-11e6-9a46-0242ac110002\x22,\x0A \x22device_id\x22: \x2277c7600c502a3d15\x22\x0A },\x0A \x22stats\x22: [\x0A {\x0A \x22timestamp\x22: \x222017-02-17T03:49:01+0000\x22,\x0A \x22software_id\x22: \x22A-ACTG\x22,\x0A \x22action_id\x22: \x22open_app\x22,\x0A \x22values\x22: {\x0A \x22device_id\x22: \x2277c7600c502a3d15\x22,\x0A \x22language\x22: \x22fr\x22\x0A }\x0A }\x0A ]\x0A}"
import json
data = json.loads(string)
print(data)
```

In your example, you had the data in a file, so you will only need to use `json.load` instead:

```
import json
data = json.load(open('ctg-stats.txt'))
print(data)
```

Comment: Tried with this solution but gives an error ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: works fine for me, and probably everyone who read this post, you sure you did exactly as my first example?

Comment: i get this string in data2  in Line no 5 and from that string i want to fetch the values.

Comment: are you trying to read the string from `ctg-stats.txt` and replace my `string` with it?